# How to Center Align Globalsign Trust Badge

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ssl, wordpress-theming

I have created a two column widget for my website footer.

**MY site:** https://www.joykatedesigns.com (look at the bottom footer)

**What I want?**

**McAfee Secure** `trust badge` centered in one column and trying to do the same for the **Globalsign** `trust badge`.

**What I have tried:**

This is proven to be very difficult. The `McAfee` was a `script/source` that I added `<center> </center>` to the code and it worked.

I haven't been able to figure this out for the globalsign code (see code below). What is the code to center this trust badge in the center of the second column?

```html
<!--- DO NOT EDIT - GlobalSign SSL Site Seal Code - DO NOT EDIT --->
<table width=125 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 title="CLICK TO VERIFY: 
This site uses a GlobalSign SSL Certificate to secure your personal 
information." >
 <tr>
   <td>
     <span id="ss_img_wrapper_gmogs_image_125-50_en_dblue">
       <a href="https://www.globalsign.com/" target=_blank title="GlobalSign Site 
         Seal" rel="nofollow"><img alt="SSL" border=0 id="ss_img" 
         src="//seal.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/images/gs_noscript_125-50_en.gif">
       </a> 
     </span>
     <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="//seal.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/gmogs_image_125-50_en_dblue.js"> 
     </script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--- DO NOT EDIT - GlobalSign SSL Site Seal Code - DO NOT EDIT --->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.footer-widgets .custom-html-widget > table {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: That worked! How about vertical alignment? I tried vertical-alignment: center; but that didn't seem to move the image.

Comment: It's hacky but without having the source to rework things you could just `.footer-widgets .custom-html-widget .ms { margin-top: 5px; }`